# Printing to console on php file

Tags: php, visual-studio, console, laravel-blade

I'm using Visual Studio to do tests on some code. The file is a .blade.php. I'm trying to print the elements in an array in an for loop by doing this:

```
for (var item in data) {
    console.log(item) }
```

Nothing shows up in my console when I do this. How can I see what items are in `data`?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing script tag

```
<script>
for (var item in data) {
    console.log(item) }
</script>
```